# Generate falling Graphics with loops and randomizers

Tags: java, swing, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need a code, more specifically a game, in which meteorites fall down and the user has to dodge them with the arrow keys.

Moving the player is not my problem. I will do this at the end.

I figured out how to create an animated object falling down, from top to bottom.

How can I create a loop which creates one new falling element every 2 seconds? The position of the element should be randomized.

This is my code at the moment:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

int x = 135;
int y = 0;

private void moveBall() {
    y = y + 1;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Meteorites");
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        game.moveBall();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *"How can I create a loop which creates one new falling element every 2 seconds?"*  Create a Swing `Timer` that fires every two seconds. Create the new meteorite when that happens. See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a game loop (gl) first of all.  The gl updates the state and position of every object on the screen and other state related objects not seen on the screen.

It should be easy for objects to register themselves to the gl.  The gl is not responsible for updating the state of every object, but it does call back every registered object to update themselves (or update other objects that it is responsible for, for example the collision detection object will update any objects on the screen that have collided).

The gl passes the current time in nano-seconds (typically) to all the objects that have registered with the gl.  For example check out the [AnimationTimer in Javafx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).  In JavaFX, by creating an AnimationTimer, and calling the start method on it, JavaFX will call your handle method on every frame... essentially registering it to JavaFX's main thread (or game loop).

So you will need to create a gl.  Register objects to it, maybe create an interface or abstract class similar to JavaFX's AnimationTimer so that objects can register themselves to your gl.  The gl should not have any Thread.sleeps in it, but if it does it should be very short and I imagine you would add it in only if your gl is going to fast, because maybe there is not a lot of stuff being calculated (hence no use crippling the CPU), but you can adjust this.  I know that working on JavaFX games I can tell you that we work very hard to keep any delays in he gl down to a minimum, hence no Thread sleeps, as this will halt the smooth flow of your animation.

The objects that get updated will track the passage of time and can execute events based on how much time has passed by.  For example you can have an object that registers itself to the gl and is responsible for putting new falling animated objects on the screen.  It can have a field for how long to wait before dropping the next item.  Since it is called every frame by the gl, it can see how much time is passing by, and when x seconds pass by, it can create and drop the next object, then reset its timer.

The animated objects falling would also be called by the gl so they can smoothly drop down.  At every frame these falling objects will calculate their new position.  Typically this is done using an interpolator (its a good idea to look into this).  Interpolators make it easy to abstract out where the position of an animating object should be relative to a fraction of time passing by.  For example if I am moving an item linearly over X distance and Y time, an interpolater will tell you how far along X distance the object should be after a percentage of Y time has passed.  Interpolators are very powerful because you can create an interpolator that moves your object not just linearly but can slow it up or speed it up (like gravity effect), it can even add bouncing effects to your objects.  So you'll want to get a firm understanding of this.  [JavaFX comes with interpolators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html).    There are also online tools I have seen in the past that let you construct your own JavaFX interpolators based on the kind of animation effect you are trying to get.

So to put it all together, have a gl, have an object that registers to the gl that is responsible for putting new falling objects on the screen, lets call this object ObjectDropper.  The ObjectDropper will implement something like AnimationTimer so it can get called every frame by your gl.  It will decide when to drop objects and can also decide the random point from where that object will drop.  You will have objects that will drop, they will be given information like where their starting point is, where their ending point is, and how long it will take to drop, and maybe even an interpolator.  These objects will also be registered to the gl and be called every frame so that they can adjust their position according to their interpolator.

This is all a very broad generic outline that tends to be true for most animated games.  There might be tools and libraries that make this all easily implemented in Swing.  As you can see JavaFX was already designed to handle many of these concepts.